# Linux standalone 'installation' of Postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql, deployment

For easy deployment, I'd like to ship an installation of Postgres as part of the application. Is it possible to include an already compiled and runnable version of Postgres that can be launched as process? I was able to do such thing with a Windows and MacOS version, but haven't found anything about Linux on that matter yet. Perhaps someone has tried this before and can share some insights...

Comment: If you do this, **please** use a non-default port so you don't tread on / conflict with any local PostgreSQL install.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's something to consider...

Comment: Your main issue is going to be that there isn't just one "Linux". You'll need to do a fair bit of work to handle compatibility with libc, be prepared to bundle your own versions of most other libs, use a wrapper script to set environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting the binaries, etc. Packaging standalone binaries under Linux is challenging even before you consider the support for different architectures (x64, x86, arm, ...). Seriously consider just letting Linux users install their own pg.

Comment: I don't really know what Postgres depends on, but just wanted to hear if someone tried this before. I can probably constrain Linux a bit more (only x64, maybe a certain distribution), but would need something that is self-contained and not dependent on anything to be installed. In the worst case, I will need to go with your suggestion.

Comment: The dependencies are somewhat configurable and distro/version dependent. Compile it and use `ldd` to examine the binaries, much like you'd use Dependency Walker on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what linux OS you're using.

Assuming it's a Redhat variant why not package your application as an RPM package? You could then declare a dependency on the standard Postgres package which would be automatically installed [yum](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum). Same principle applies if you're using Debian based systems, just a different packaging format.

From the user's perspective the OS's native packaging format is always the easiest way to install your application. Just requires effort to package it properly.

Comment: It'll probably be a Debian-kind of distribution. The problem with a package installation is that it'll be installed system-wide which I don't want.

Comment: @orange Don't understand why system-side installation is such a problem. A single Postgres database is more than capable of hosting multiple database instances. You did ask for "easy" deployment packaging your app means you can leverage the OS's application management functionality. Don't forget upgrades and removal.

Answer (score 0):

You can find cross-platform binaries from these pages on PostgreSQL official website:

- For easy GUI .run installers, use links provided at http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload.
- If your target machine has no X installed on it, or you want to automate installation process with shell scripts, then you can download RPM or Deb packages from http://community.openscg.com/se/postgresql/packages.jsp

I found these links on http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/, under "Cross distribution packages" and "Graphical installer".

I quote from those pages:

> Note: The cross distribution packages do not fully integrate with the platform-specific packaging systems.
>
> You must have root priviliges to install these packages, however, none of your systems library files will be altered. The supporting libraries that these binaries require are included locally as part of the install. This is the "special sauce" that allows identical binaries to run on different linux distro's.

Comment: I just noticed that .run installers can also accept command-line switches.